# Why is my program's self CPU time so low compared to total CPU time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization

I am using the Visual Studio performance profiler to see what part of my code is running slow, as I noticed that it took over 15 minutes to run. However, after getting the performance back, I see that *self CPU time is extremely low (0.03% per function, max)*. See the picture below

[image]

When I click on my detailed report I get the "exclusive samples" statistics. This shows that most of the CPU time is gone to various .dll files.

[image]

This is extremely annoying as i'm trying to speed up the code by optimizing some parts, but apparently almost no execution time is taken by the script itself. Does anyone know what kind of error I might have made or how to fix the diagnostics tool?

Comment: I bet you perform a lot of unnecessary vector reallocations. Anyway, it is almost useless without showing code causing this behavior. Also make sure that you are profiling Release build with optimizations enabled.

Comment: Just because your self CPU is low doesn't mean you can't figure out whats wrong. It's telling you the runtime is slow, and it's slow at the vector constructor call. So you're probably creating a lot of unnecessary vectors that all take up dynamic storage space.